# How do I find the restriction of $\sqrt{\frac{2 x+3}{7 x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the Restriction of the following expression: $$\sqrt{\frac{2 x+3}{7 x}}$$
When it comes to finding restrictions, I know I must find the restriction of a fraction that has a denominator with a variable:

1. 7x = 0
2. x = 0
3. (-∞,0)∪(0,∞+)

And I know I must find the restriction of a radicand which contains a variable:

1. $\frac{2 x+3}{7 x}$ ≥ 0
2. (-∞,-$\frac{3}{2}$)∪(0,∞+)

Considering that the expression contains both a radical with a variable within its radicand and a fraction with a variable within its denominator, how do I find the restriction of $$\sqrt{\frac{2 x+3}{7 x}}$$

Any help would be greatly apprecciated.

Comment: You need to settle on the most restrictive of the two cases.  This would be number 2.  in your analysis.

Comment: @ SimonSatn11 At x=-1.5 it has a zero. At x=0 it has a pole. Domain is restricted outside  these points on x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{2x+3}{7x}\ge 0$ and $x \ne 0$.